# Higher order type function with nested property access

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assume I have an interface like below.

```
interface Nested { 
  x: { b: { c: { d: "e"}}};
  y: { b: { c: { d: "f"}}};
}
```

It is possible to generate two types from it as below.

```
type E = Nested['x']['b']['c']['d'];
type F = Nested['y']['b']['c']['d'];
```

However I would like to avoid repeating ['b']['c']['d'] each time, and instead do something like

```
type E = NestedBCD<'x'>
type F = NestedBCD<'y'>
```

Basically, a higher order function of sort that operate on types.
Is something like this possible in Typescript?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCbIN7IAeAXPsgEakEJXLakDkEDAvmwDTICetlZNZesgYxWbFgCgJYLgAcUAUWQBeNJhwBtBoQYBdLeT1aERhtj0BuaXJQAxFWqwRsWrqcP6GJz%20d1WpQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with type aliases:

```
interface Nested { x: { b: { c: { d: 'e'}}}, y: { b: { c: { d: 'f'}}}}

type NestedBCD<T extends keyof Nested> = Nested[T]["b"]["c"]["d"];
type E = NestedBCD<"x">;
type F = NestedBCD<"y">;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCbIN7IAeAXPsgEakEJXLakDkEDAvmwDTICetlZNZesgYxWbFgCgJYLgAcU6LBGwAhAMIARADwAVZBEKQQ2DMgDWELgHsYaTDgB8yALx2l2ANo6Auh4BE5H6+fghB-thBANzScigAoi5uOOrafoR+DtEy8sgAYomKyZpaflwZ0UA)

Comment: Hi, this fails (as expected) when y: doesn't contain b but i would like it to fail against `type F =` instead of `type NestedBCD` - is there a way to handle this?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCbIN7IAeAXPsgEakEJXLakDkEDAvmwDTICetEtNZesgYxWbFgCgJYLgAcU6LBGwAhAMIARADwAVZBEKQQ2DMgDWELgHsYaTDgB8yALx2l2ANo6Auh4BE5H6+fghB-thBANzScigAoi5uOOrafoR+DtEy8sgAYomKyZpaflwZ0UA)